# Passing Dynamic OG title, description and image to Facebook share dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to implement a dynamic facebook share button that shares a custom "title" + "description" on the same URL for every quote, here: http://codepen.io/ryanabi/pen/mVoJGp

The problem is that Facebook doesn't allow passing custom parameters but only using the main header OG tags... which is I can't change dynamically as I am using jQuery not PHP.

Any advice on how to pass a different title + image but with the same URL.

```js
//this array is declared outside the $(document).ready function to make it accessible in
 //both $(document).ready and changeQuote() function
   var quote = [
    {
   quotes: '"Keep all Jealous people away from you"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Massage twice a week"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Use cocoa butter in vibe + dove body soap"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Keep a clean heart and clean soul"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Take care of your plants"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Keep the pathway to more success clean"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Surround yourself with greatness"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Stay focussed"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"The ones closest to you want to see you fail"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Keep your head above water"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Dont be a crab"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Work hard"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Give Thanks"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Never give up on the journey"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"You must believe"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Name your plants"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Cardio is important"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Brush your teeth"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"There will be struggle before success"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Have a lot of pillows"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
    {
   quotes: '"Use mouth wash"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Enjoy life"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"You have to work hard for success"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"3 multi vitamin gummies per day"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Set iguanas free away from flowers"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Never disappoint your loved ones"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Keep the theory smooth"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Bless up"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Foot rubs"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"They have to know what you are saying"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Jus know"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Smell like success"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Take rest"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Give thanks to the most high"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Drink water every morning"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Believe in yourself"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Have egg whites for breakfast every day"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Drink coconut water"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"No pork"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Salt water"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Dry your back"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Have the key to every door"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Have apples"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"When people close the door on you just open it"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Keep Blocking, Keep Dunking, Keep winning"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Manicure and Pedicure once a week"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Dont Panic"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Never Give Up"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Take the trash in your life out"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Surround yourself with angles"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Overcome the roadblocks"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Make it"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Be better than the evil people"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"The better the landscaping the more success"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Gluten free in all your food"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Embrace your blessing"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Dont let people pull you down"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Have a hammock"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Never fold"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Clear your mind and find peace and love"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Keep people around you thats gonna uplift you"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Over stand never understand"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Move forward"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"You have to make it through the jungle to make it to paradise"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"In the jungle there is a lot of they. You must overcome they to make it to paradise"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"When you win, you must celebrate"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Almond milk and cinnamon toast crunch"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Stay clean at all times"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Dont entertain they, keep they away from you and tell they to bow down"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Stat fresh, Stay blessed"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"They want you to stop. Never stop"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Weather the storm"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Vitamin C"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Find happiness and embrace it"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Always remember"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Make the right choices"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Have good relationships"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Counter Sue"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Never back down"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Be honest"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Dont care about the haters"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Dont make decisions when you are in a bad mood"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
   quotes: '"Stay on course**"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    },
      {
        quotes: '"Believing in GOD!!! Loving GOD!!!GOD IS THE GREATEST!!!"',
        speaker: "DJ Khaled"
      },
    {
   quotes: '"Clean face"',
   speaker: "DJ Khaled"
    }
  ];
 
 $(document).ready(function() {

  //adding an onclick function to newQuote button. just calling the changeQuote() function in it
   $("#newQuote").click(function() {    
   changeQuote();
  });     
 
 //calling changeQuote() in $(document).ready function so that a random quote shows on page load
 changeQuote();
  
  
 });
 
 //made a function to change quote so that it can be used in $(document).ready and 
 //newQuote button on click event
 function changeQuote(){
  var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);
  
    $("#quotes").fadeOut('fast', function() {
   $("#quotes").text(quote[randomQuote].quotes).fadeIn(700);
   
   //searching the anchors by their unique id and setting their href attribute
   
   
   $('#tweetme').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + $('#quotes').html() + $("#speaker").text(" -" + quote[randomQuote].speaker).html() + ' @ryanabii');
   $('#facebookit').attr('href', 'https://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + 'http://codepen.io/ryanabi/pen/mVoJGp' );
    });
    
    $("#speaker").fadeOut('fast', function() {
   $("#speaker").text("-" + quote[randomQuote].speaker).fadeIn(700);
    });
 }

//change the bg color

$(function(){
    $('#anotherone').click(function() {
       document.body.style.background = getRandomColor();
    });
});

 function getRandomColor() {
     var bgColorArray = ['#DFD9C9','#F5D5CE','#F1F5EA','#AEDBC9','#F3F7FF','#E8AB9C','#FFE9BD','#F1FFC7','#B7E8D8','#E1EDFF','#D3FFF6','#F5E4C9','#FFD3DE','#BBB7E8','#E7F5C7','#EEEEEE','#'],
    selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectBG;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #E4FFEC;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

p, h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: bebas-neue, sans-serif;
  font-size: 66px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h2 {
  font-family: kotta-one, serif;
}

h4 {
  font-family: cabin;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  font-family: cabin;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 110%;
}

.heading a {
  float: right;
  top:0;
}

#anotherone {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom:20%;
}

#main {
  backgroud-color: #E4FFEC;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 860px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.changebg {
    background-color: #86E2D5 !important;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

#newQuote {
  font-family: cabin;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#quotes, #speaker {
  text-align: center;
}

#quotes {
  font-family: kotta-one;
  font-size: 58px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#speaker {
  font-family: cabin;
  font-size: 125%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#tweetme {
  color: #00aced;
  transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

#tweetme:hover {
  color: #4099FF;
  transform: translate(2px,-2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(2px,-2px);
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
}

.another-button {
 padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: #2ECC71;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #27AE60;
  transition: all 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  z-index: 2;
  
}

.another-button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: translate(0px,-2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-2px);
 border-bottom: 5px solid #27AE60;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  z-index: 2;
}

.another-button:focus {
  outline:0;
}

.another-button:active
{
 transform: translate(0px,3px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,3px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid #27ae60;
}


.main-quote {
  padding-top: 50px;
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow: none;
}

.footer {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:90px;
  
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  line-height:1.3;
  
}

.footer a {
  color: #2ECC71;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.footer a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translate(0px,3px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,3px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid #2ECC71;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/bebas-neue;kotta-one;cabin.js"></script> 
</head>

 <body id = "main">
    <div class= "heading"> 
      <h1>Keys to success</h1>
      <p><i>#blessup</i></p>
      <a target="_blank" id="tweetme"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
   
    <div class = "main-quote">
    <div id = "quotes">
    </div>
    <div id = "speaker">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id = "anotherone">
      <button class="btn another-button" id = "newQuote">ANOTHER ONE!</button> 
      
    </div>
   
   <div class="footer">
     <p>Design by <a href="#">yours truly</a></p>
     <p>List by <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/pathwaytomoresuccess/comments/3wleje/the_complete_list_of_keys_to_success_and_things/" target="_blank">pbaylis</a></p>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Regards,

Comment: Share dialog doesn’t take those additional parameters any more – but the Feed dialog still does. Btw., it would perhaps make more sense to have an individual URL for each quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, Here's a statement from Facebook regarding this issue:

> We have changed the behavior of the sharer plugin to be consistent
>   with other plugins and features on our platform.
>
> The sharer will **no longer accept custom parameters** and facebook will
>   pull the information that is being displayed in the preview the same
>   way that it would appear on facebook as a post, from the url OG meta
>   tags.

source: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/